# How to exit from spark program

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how do i exit (by forcing an error message) from Spark program if for example -my join condition fails?

Example-

Employee data-  emp_id, dep_no

1,1001
2,2001

Department data- dep_no,dept_name, location

1001,xyz,NY
3001,pqr,PA

Now if i want to enrich Employee data, i need to do a join with department data. All i want is whenever I don’t find a department in dept data (my join will fail), i want to stop the process (error out) with a custom error message in Spark (Scala).

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Use Try Catch in code throw custom Exception

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you may want to use one of the following SparkContext's methods:

```
def cancelJob(jobId: Int, reason: String): Unit 
def cancelJobGroup(groupId: String)
def cancelAllJobs()
```

A few useful calls:

```
def applicationId: String // to get current jobId
def setJobGroup(groupId: String, description: String, interruptOnCancel: Boolean = false) // to set groupId for all Spark jobs to be created by the current thread
```